# Colouring in-line text within verbatim environment

Tags: color, verbatim

I wish colour some selected text within the verbatim environment. These texts may not occupy a whole line, but rather be a small part of a line.

An illustration is given below. Say for example, in the first line of this code, `from` and `import` are to be written in purple colour, while the rest of the line is in usual black colour. I am using `fancyvrb` package, but cannot figure out how to do this. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want `import` and `from` coloured differently from the other keywords?

Comment: Have you tried using [tag:listings] or [tag:minted] to do this? They have a lot of options for syntax highlighting code.

Comment: @Henri, It want them coloured differently because its a part of a code, and I want it to look similar in my text document as in the code itself.

Comment: Thanks @ArunDebray,  I have not tried them.  Can you enlighten me a bit more on those?